# $|H\cap K| = |H\cap yKy^{-1}|$ for any $y \in G $??

Tags: group-theory

It is obviously absurd, since if I take any subgroup $H$ which is not normal in $G$ and put $K=H$ the statement can't be true.

It is some other exercise that I got above wrong conclusion from. The exercise asks to prove that if $G=HK $ then $G=H^xK^y$ for any $x$, $y \in G$ (superscript denoting conjugation $xHx^{-1}$).

Before the exercise, I checked that $HK=G $ iff $[H:H\cap K]=[G:K] $. With this and the statement in the exercise, I deduce as follows : 
If $G=HK^y=HK$, $[G:K^y]=[H:H\cap K^y]$ and $[G:K^y]=[G:K]=[H:H\cap K]$. Thus $|H\cap K|=|H\cap K^y|$

Where would have I possibly gone wrong?

Comment: The statement in your title does not include the hypothesis $G=HK$.

Comment: Well you seem to be assuming that all of the groups around are finite, but this was not assumed in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You prove that if $G=HK=HK^y$ then $|H\cap K|=|H\cap K^y|$. But for general
subgroups $H$ and $K$, you expect $G\ne HK$. This is the case when $K=H\ne G$,
so one cannot deduce that $|H\cap K|=|H\cap K^y|$ in general.